# Como remover arquivos de upload depois do comando db:drop no Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Minha API utiliza a [gem shrine](https://github.com/janko-m/shrine) para efetivar diversos tipos diferente de uploads. Infelizmente durante o desenvolvimento os arquivos estão se acumulando na pasta `public/uploads` toda vez que faço `db:drop` da base de dados e rodo novamente.

Minhas factories (Factory Girl) injetam esses arquivos através de fixtures.

É possível que toda vez que rodar o comando `db:drop` se apague todos os arquivos na pasta `public/uploads`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução é simples, crie uma tarefa chamada `cleanup` com o método `uploads`:

```
rails g task cleanup uploads
```

Agora adicione o código abaixo a está tarefa:

```
namespace :cleanup do
  desc 'Removes all Shrine uploads'
  task uploads: :environment do
    FileUtils.rm_rf Dir.glob("#{Rails.root}/public/uploads/*")
  end
end

Rake::Task['db:drop'].enhance do
  Rake::Task['cleanup:uploads'].invoke
end
```

Toda vez que chamar o comando `db:drop` será invocado em seguida `cleanup:uploads`.

Espero que ajude outros desenvolvedores, isso é muito útil!